# How can I change the background for the entire page?

Tags: css, react-native

So I'm using React native and I'm having a problem with most of my pages,
I can't seem to change the entire background color to a unified color for all elements.
i.e:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View, Text, FlatList, ActivityIndicator } from "react-native";
import { List, ListItem, SearchBar } from "react-native-elements";


class Animals extends Component {


  render() {
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          flexDirection: 'row',
          height: 100,
          padding: 20,
          backgroundColor: 'gray'
        }}>
        <Text>Hello World!</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default Animals;
```

And that's what I'm getting:
[image]

How can I make the background color to be for the entire screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `flex`, so the desired code will be:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View, Text, FlatList, ActivityIndicator } from "react-native";

class Animals extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          backgroundColor: "gray"
        }}
      >
        <Text>Hello World!</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default Animals;
```

> Also take a look at [Flex - Docs!](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flexbox.html)

Answer (score 0):

Change your styles to add `%` where applicable. Keeping them off will make the html interpret it as `px` which in your case is 100 pixels. https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View, Text, FlatList, ActivityIndicator } from "react-native";
import { List, ListItem, SearchBar } from "react-native-elements";


class Animals extends Component {


  render() {
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          flexDirection: 'row',
          height: '100%',
          padding: '20px',
          backgroundColor: 'gray'
        }}>
        <Text>Hello World!</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default Animals;
```

edit: updated styling

Comment: you can't use `%` without quotes!

Comment: Sorry, I am an angular coder and do all my styling in .css files. so I don't know how  react styling is formatted. but either way I added the link as a reference